# How to extract unique rows depending on rule?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this

id_1,date_1,id_2,date_2

I need dataframe where rows (date_1 + 15 days) < date_2
in case where this rule is match I need only first occurence

Just using boolean mask is not solve the problem

So I think may be I need to use
some kind of`for index, row in df.iterrows():`
and create new dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
df[['date_1', 'date_2']] = df[['date_1', 'date_2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['date_1_15'] = df['date_1'] + timedelta(4)

def apply_mask(row):
    if row['date_1_15'] < row['date_2']:
        row['mask'] = True
    else:
        row['mask'] = False
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row: apply_mask(row), axis=1)
dx = df.loc[df['mask'] == True]
dx = dx.groupby(['date_1']).first()
dx['mask_first'] = True
dx = dx.reset_index()
dx = dx[['date_1', 'date_2', 'mask_first']]
df = pd.merge(df, dx, on=['date_1', 'date_2'], how='outer')
```

Comment: thanks, I think you almost there, can we do it without grouping by date_1, since it drops many values

Comment: it drops many values because they do not match the case < 15 days and it is not the results of groupby.

Comment: here you have the updated code with final df with column 'mask_first' marking first occurence as True

Comment: don't hesitate to accept my answer as OK if you like it :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id_1':[1,2,3,4], 
                        'date1': ['2018-01-10', '2018-02-05', '2018-02-20', '2018-02-21'],
                        'date2': ['2018-01-11', '2018-02-15', '2018-02-27', '2018-02-22']})


df[['date1', 'date2']] = df[['date1', 'date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)


df['date1_15'] = df['date1'] + timedelta(15)
df = df.loc[df['date1_15'] < df['date2']].head(1)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. let me clarify. this approach works only in general case, but it doesn't care about uniqueness and first occurence. when it see first occurence it should extract this row so it doesn't affect next round of checking

Comment: You have asked to check with a rule and get first occurence of the data matching the rule. I have done it for you. So, please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: It is nice approach to solve the problem If I need to use boolean mask to solve +15 days rule,but problem is little bit tricky. Any way thank you for your time.

Comment: clarify your questions. do you want to group by date1?

Comment: please look at the question, if you look at dictionary you will see what I mean

Comment: please see new answer based on updated question with dd (dictionary) provided. the provided dictionary (dd) matches one result only.